# Two honeycomb hints (yet another 'find the next number in the sequence')

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

> Find the next number in the sequence $1,7,74,\dots$

First hint:

> [image]

Second hint:

> [image]

To clarify: the 'hints' are really clues. They are hidden, because **any of the two alone** could be enough to solve the puzzle. So, anyone who is interested, can look up only one hint, or both.

There is a simple rule for both cases, all the blanks can be filled and the sequence can be continued *ad infinitum*.

Comment: Refreshingly large clues/data ratio! (just 3 actual data and 2000 words worth of clues)

Comment: @humn, thanks then. This is my first post here

Comment: Seeing the solution, I like this even more, as a solver gets to travel along further clues as they develop. Also clever how the same number is reached in multiple settings.  Is this original?

Comment: @humn, I made it up, and I haven't seen this sequence (or the arrays as a whole) anywhere

Comment: Looks like a new take on Minesweeper. :)

Comment: I wonder what was the reason for the downvote: I would like to improve

Comment: Don't worry about uselessly uncommented drive-by downvotes, even posts with 150+ upvotes get meaningless downvotes from sourpusses.

Comment: The comb with multiple black squares hints at an endless genre of mazes, even when the secret is known. Somewhat like what seems to be called [Hidato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidato), but I think even more interesting. Negative entries could help keep the numbers from getting too big.

Comment: Do you mind if I go and display this in the [site's main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)?

Comment: @humn, no, not at all

Comment: If you want to post another puzzle, go ahead and do it in a new question!

Comment: @humn, I decided to post the second case as a new question after all

Comment: Be sure to give a vote of recognition vote for this puzzle (and others) at 
[_Best puzzles of 2016, July– Sep_](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5555/18129).
You too, @Yuriy S, please vote for your own puzzle
to make up for my not being allowed to vote for it
(because I nominated it).

Comment: @humn, thank you very much for the nomination, but I wouldn't want to vote for myself. I'm sure there are a lot of great puzzles nominated

Comment: Another one inspired by this puzzle: [_How to fill a honeymoon_](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43936/how-to-fill-a-honeymoon)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer is, after some minor corrections:

> 1017.

Because:

> [image]

The rule is that

> you fill out the honeycomb by simply adding the sum of the surrounding cells into the next cell clockwise.

The second hint can be filled out analogously:

> [image]

It would be interesting to see in another solution what is the mathematics behind this *rule*. I suspect nice recursions lurking behind the scenes.

Comment: Indeed, as 129+12+14=155. Thanks.

Comment: Now it is correct. Would you like to fill in the hexagons below as well?

Comment: I see now that it follows (perhaps) exactly the same rule. I will do that.

Comment: Matsmath, I added another case, I hope you don't mind

Comment: If the answer to that puzzle is different from this, then I would suggest you to start another post on that. Perhaps there are others who would like to pursue that challenge.