# Two honeycomb hints, part two (find the next number)

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

Another variant of my [previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42884/two-honeycomb-hints-yet-another-find-the-next-number-in-the-sequence), this one might be easier (or harder).

> What is the next number in the sequence $1, 2,6, 16, ...$?

To clarify: the 'hints' are really clues. They are hidden, because a**ny of the two alone** could be enough to solve the puzzle. So, anyone who is interested, can look up only one hint, or both.

First hint:

> [image]

Second hint:

> [image]

Comment: As the "hints" are _required_ to solve the puzzle (lest it be far too broad) they probably should not be spoilered (and possibly not even referred to as hints...)

Comment: @Will, someone edited and added spoilers. I decided to keep them. The point is - ONE hint is enough, any of the two. I'll clarify

Comment: Technically, they might have been intended as _clues_ rather than _hints_, especially as 4 numbers alone are never enough for a sequence.

Comment: @humn, the word 'hints' was used because it goes well with the 'honeycomb'

Comment: You are a puzzler and a poet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the basis of the second hint the answer is evidently

> 42

unless I have miscalculated. The idea is that you

> proceed clockwise and inward to fill the triangle, starting with a 1 at top left and always filling each cell with the sum of the adjacent numbers you have so far. The black cell is the last one to be filled.

I think (but haven't checked) that the idea of the first hint is that

> you start with a 1 and form triangles by a clockwise outward spiral, and each time you form a new triangle larger than its predecessor you record the number in its final cell.

Comment: You are right. As for the first hint, it's probably harder to figure out

Comment: Having got the second, the first seems pretty straightforward, and I've amended my answer to say what I think is going on there. I haven't checked the actual arithmetic to verify that it works, but it seems like it should.

Comment: Well, there are other ways to describe the same thing (e.g., the number of steps you go before turning increases by 1 each time, and there's a shaded cell at the end of each run of same-direction steps) and what's simplest is a matter of taste. Or do you mean my description is actually wrong?

Comment: I think we may be at cross purposes. The after-the-comma stuff is just saying where the black cells go, which is not the same in the first and second hints.

Comment: Gareth, I want to thank you for your insight, since you are right, the sequence is formed by the last numbers of a finished triangle, and this rule also works for hexagons from the previous question and for any ofther cases I considered. Now I understand this a little better

Answer (score 3):

Taking the baton from
[Gareth McCaughan’s](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42888/18129)
solution to the bottom honeycomb hint, pictured as...

> [image]
>  
> ... where trails begin at the top left corners and proceed in
>  triangular clockwise inward spirals...

...here is how the top honeycomb hint not only gets to the same...

> ...[answer = **42**](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(answer))...

...but also...

> ...must proceed beyond it before all the honeycomb hint cells have honey.
>  
>             
>  [image]
>  
>  This time a triangular clockwise outward spiral
>  begins at the non-black-cell with 1.

As described by
[Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42888/18129)...

> ...each black cell is presumed to be empty before the trail gets there,
>  and each cell to be filled in gets the sum of the numbers
>  already filled in for its neighbors.

Comment: I accepted Gareth's answer, since he was the first and gave the solution in principle, even if without illustrations. I hope you don't mind. You filled all the blanks exactly right

Comment: Good, just wanted to join the fun once the dust had settled