# Honeydripping around the clock

Tags: no-computers, mazes, graph-theory, calculation-puzzle

[image]

**What path could a honeybee follow,
beginning and ending at top center,
visiting every empty cell exactly once
and dripping 2 drops of honey into the last cell?**

- Start by heading clockwise from the cell at top center,
  which has 12 honeydrops.
  Eleven other cells begin with numbers of drops
  that correspond to hours.
- Each step consists of moving to an adjacent cell and dripping
  0, 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 or 9
  drops into it based on how many total drops
  its (1 to 6) neighboring cells, combined,
  contain **at that moment**.
- Each number of new honeydrops is the **ones digit** of the surrounding total.
- The two top cells indicated by arrows
  are the beginning and end of the path
  and should each receive **2** drops,
  with the central **12** included in their totals.

**No need to spoilerize a text solution.**
  Site implementation makes that unduly onerous.

Also no need to be daunted by apparent complexity.
The path is quite constrained topologically
and luck alone probably gives a 1/10 chance of
ending correctly.

A little well-directed reckoning can help approach this
in a way that eases recovery from inevitable addition mistakes.
(Yes, this claim follows much misdirected reckoning and many mistakes.)

The following possible sequence of seven initial steps
demonstrates how the path works.

[image]

The first two steps here drip **2** drops each
because the only adjacent honey on the first step
is 1**2** (last digit = 2)
and on the second step is simply 2.
The seventh step drips **5** drops as
the total of its surrounding cells is 1+3+7+7+7 = 2**5**
(last digit = 5).

This is meant to be convenient on paper or in a text editor.
 
Here is a template for `<pre>...</pre>`:

```
                             ___     ___     ___
                         ___/   \___/ 12\___/   \___
                     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___/   \___
                 ___/ 11\___/   \___/   \___/   \___/ 1 \___
             ___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___
            /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \
            \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
         ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___
        / 10\___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/ 2 \
        \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/
     ___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___
    /   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \
    \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/
    /   \___/   \___/   \___/                   \___/   \___/   \___/   \
    \___/           \___/   \                   /   \___/           \___/
    / 9 \           /   \___/                   \___/   \           / 3 \
    \___/           \___/   \                   /   \___/           \___/
    /   \___     ___/   \___/                   \___/   \___     ___/   \
    \___/   \___/   \___/   \___             ___/   \___/   \___/   \___/
    /   \___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___/   \
    \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/
        \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/
        / 8 \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/ 4 \
        \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/
            \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
            /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \
            \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
                \___/ 7 \___/   \___     ___/   \___/ 5 \___/
                    \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/
                        \___/   \___/ 6 \___/   \___/
                            \___/   \___/   \___/
```

And here is how the seven-step example could begin to resemble a maze:

```
                             ___     ___     ___
                         ___/   \___/ 12\___/ 2 \___
                     ___/   \___/   \___/ 2  ___  3 \___
                 ___/ 11\___/   \___/   \___/ 7  ___/ 1 \___
                /   \___/   \___/           \   / 5 \___/   \
                \___/   \___/   \           / 7 \       \___/
                    \___/   \___/           \___  7 \___/
                        \___/   \           /   \___/
                            \___/           \___/
```

This puzzle forthrightly, though incompletely, imitates
[*Two honeycomb hints*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42884)
by
[Yuriy S](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30250/yuriy-s).

Comment: You must eat honeycomb for breakfast, lunch and dinner considering how much you love it :P

Comment: You really love honeycomb *too much*. Just search for [`user:18129 views:0 honeycomb`](/search?q=user%3A18129+views%3A0+honeycomb). Really though, can you even eat honeycomb?

Comment: Only took [_Two honeycomb hints_](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42884) to become stuck on this sweet path

Comment: @humn No, not exactly. These were just hexagonal patterns, you made the connection with *honeycomb*. humn LOOOOOOOVZ HONEYCOMB

Comment: Would [tag:graph-theory] be appropriate?

Comment: Good idea to tag with [tag:graph-theory], @ghosts_in_the_code,
this even has two different levels of arcs.

Comment: I wonder if I could write an A* Algorithm to solve this... :P (Yes I know it says no-computers)

Comment: Would be interesting to find out (by computer) if the end really does have a 1/10 chance of being each digit, @dcfyj.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so there are probably other paths, but the one I found ends with a honeycomb that looks like this (I deleted some lines so you can see the path taken, like in the maze example given above):

> ```
>                              ___     ___     ___
>                          ___/ 1 \___/ 12\___/ 2 \___
>                      ___/ 2  ___  2 \___  2  ___  3 \___
>                  ___/ 11\___  9 \___/   \___/ 1 \   / 1 \___
>              ___/ 8 \___/ 2  ___/           \     4 \___/ 5 \___
>             / 9 \     7 \___  7 \           / 5 \___/ 4  ___  5 \
>             \     8 \___  7  ___/           \___  9  ___/ 4  ___/
>          ___/ 9 \___/   \___/ 0 \___     ___/ 6 \___/   \___  1 \___
>         / 10\   /           \     0 \___/ 9     /           \   / 2 \
>         \___/ 9 \           / 0 \   / 0  ___/ 2 \           / 3 \___/
>      ___/ 3  ___/           \   / 0  ___/ 1  ___/           \___  5 \___
>     / 1  ___/ 6 \___     ___/ 0 \___/   \___  1 \___     ___/ 6 \___  5 \
>     \   / 6  ___  6 \___/ 0  ___/           \___  1 \___/ 6  ___  8 \   /
>     / 5  ___/   \___  6 \   /                   \   / 6  ___/   \___  8 \
>     \___/           \   / 0 \                   / 5 \   /           \___/
>     / 9 \           / 6 \   /                   \   / 6 \           / 3 \
>     \___/           \   / 0 \                   / 3 \   /           \___/
>     / 0 \___     ___/ 6 \   /                   \   / 6 \___     ___/ 9 \
>     \     2 \___/ 6  ___/ 0 \___             ___/ 1 \___  6 \___/ 6     /
>     / 1 \___  6  ___/   \___  0 \___     ___/ 5  ___/   \___  6  ___/ 5 \
>     \___  1 \___/           \___  0 \___/ 1  ___/           \___/ 1  ___/
>         \___  3 \           / 8 \___  8 \___  4 \           / 1  ___/
>         / 8 \   /           \     8  ___/ 7  ___/           \   / 4 \
>         \___/ 5 \___     ___/ 6 \___/   \___  7 \___     ___/ 5 \___/
>             \___  1 \___/ 2 \   /           \___  6 \___/ 0 \   /
>             / 6  ___/ 9     / 6 \           / 1  ___/ 5     / 5 \
>             \___  6  ___/ 0 \   /           \   / 0  ___/ 0  ___/
>                 \___/ 7 \   / 6 \___     ___/ 1 \   / 5 \___/
>                     \___/ 1 \___  2 \___/ 1  ___/ 5 \___/
>                         \___  8  ___/ 6 \___  5  ___/
>                             \___/   \___/   \___/
> ```

As to how I got to this answer, I first set about finding a valid path that visited every cell. The first path I found ended with 4, so then I just needed to tweak the end of the path a little bit to get it to work.

As to how I found a path in the first place

> There are a few cells in the clock which are only connected to two other cells
> What this means is that cell must be traversed in a fixed order (well, two orders, either forwards or backwards). This happens in 8 places, marked with an X.
>
> ```
>                              ___     ___     ___
>                          ___/   \___/ 12\___/   \___
>                      ___/   \___/   \___/   \___/   \___
>                  ___/ 11\___/   \___/   \___/   \___/ 1 \___
>              ___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___
>             /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \
>             \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
>          ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___
>         / 10\___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/ 2 \
>         \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/
>      ___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___
>     /   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \
>     \   /   \___  X \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/ X  ___/   \   /
>     / X  ___/   \___    \___/                   \___/    ___/   \___  X \
>     \___/           \___/   \                   /   \___/           \___/
>     / 9 \           /   \___/                   \___/   \           / 3 \
>     \___/           \___/   \                   /   \___/           \___/
>     / X \___     ___/   \___/                   \___/   \___     ___/ X \
>     \       \___/ X  ___/   \___             ___/   \___  X \___/       /
>     /   \___/    ___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___    \___/   \
>     \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/
>         \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/
>         / 8 \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/ 4 \
>         \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/
>             \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
>             /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \
>             \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
>                 \___/ 7 \___/   \___     ___/   \___/ 5 \___/
>                     \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/
>                         \___/   \___/ 6 \___/   \___/
>                             \___/   \___/   \___/
> ```

Then:

> From there, I came up with these partial paths, let's use lowercase letters to show the steps from a to s:
>
> ```
>                              ___     ___     ___
>                          ___/   \___/ 12\___/   \___
>                      ___/   \___/   \___/   \___/   \___
>                  ___/ 11\___/   \___/   \___/   \___/ 1 \___
>              ___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___
>             /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \
>             \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
>          ___/ s \___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___/ a \___
>         / 10\   /           \___/   \___/   \___/           \   / 2 \
>         \___/ r \           /   \___/   \___/   \           / b \___/
>      ___/ q  ___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___  c \___
>     / p  ___/ m \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/ g \___  d \
>     \   / n  ___  l \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/ h  ___  f \   /
>     / o  ___/   \___  k \___/                   \___/ i  ___/   \___  e \
>     \___/           \   /   \                   /   \   /           \___/
>     / 9 \           / j \___/                   \___/ j \           / 3 \
>     \___/           \   /   \                   /   \   /           \___/
>     / e \___     ___/ i \___/                   \___/ k \___     ___/ o \
>     \     f \___/ h  ___/   \___             ___/   \___  l \___/ n     /
>     / d \___  g  ___/   \___/   \___     ___/   \___/   \___  m  ___/ p \
>     \___  c \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/ q  ___/
>         \___  b \           /   \___/   \___/   \           / r  ___/
>         / 8 \   /           \___/   \___/   \___/           \   / 4 \
>         \___/ a \___     ___/   \___/   \___/   \___     ___/ s \___/
>             \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
>             /   \___/   \___/   \           /   \___/   \___/   \
>             \___/   \___/   \___/           \___/   \___/   \___/
>                 \___/ 7 \___/   \___     ___/   \___/ 5 \___/
>                     \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/
>                         \___/   \___/ 6 \___/   \___/
>                             \___/   \___/   \___/
> ```

Then I started thinking about how to fill the middle circle of the clock.

> The only openings into the center are now at 1, 5, 7, and 11.
> So I decided the best route would be one that filled in the area around 1 o'clock, did the partial loopy path from 2 to 4 o'clock,
> and then, starting near 5 o'clock, circle around the inner loop, exiting at 7 o'clock.
> Then you do the partial path from 8 to 10, fill in the area around 11, and then you're done.

As to how I picked specific steps in that more general path, I honestly just picked whichever direction came first if you were thinking clockwise whenever there was a choice to make. As I said, this originally led me to a path ending with the number 4, not 2, but fixing it was fairly trivial, I just changed some choices I made filling in the area around 11 o'clock.

Comment: Your analysis of the maze is even better than I had hoped,
thank you for taking the trouble to lay it out (spoilered even!)
and all the more so for listing the path as `BA...B`.
I've tried a few times, and still hope to be overlooking something,
but I just can't get the same number as you at two places.
(continued in the next two comments)

Comment: At the first touch of **2**,
at the end of `...AABDB`,
I get 4+5+2 = **1** instead of **9**.
Fortunately, the difference seems to cancel out within a few more steps!
As arduous as this maze may be, it is actually quite forgiving.

Comment: Halfway between **10** and **11** on the perimeter,
at the end of `...AAFAE`,
I get 9+9 = **8** instead of **9**.
If this turns out to be the case,
slight changes there and a little later
can rescue the ending.
The nearby cluster of **0**s is something I hoped to see
and it provides an extra path-change option that might come in handy.
Don't forget to add the **12** at high noon/midnight
when adding up for the final **2**.

Comment: @humn oh shoot, you're right I missed that. I can fix this later I think.

Comment: i fixed the first error, still figuring out how to refactor the path for the ending...

Comment: I'm fairly positive this is right now, and I made the paths clearer by taking out lines instead of using the A-F path thing

Comment: Very nicely done and explained.  I'd just started working a bit on it.  Cool stuff!

Answer (score 3):

**Wrap-up: the making of
[*Honeydripping
 around the clock*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44090/)**

*This is not a solution to the puzzle but provides notes from its poser.
 This type of answer has been
 [approved by the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

***Caution:** This post contains information about the solution.*

---

This is the third experiment with self-defining
[hexagonal-tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling)
mazes inspired by
[*Two honeycomb hints*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42884/)
and, especially,
[*Two honeycomb hints, part two*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42887/)
by
[Yuriy S](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30250/yuriy-s).

[image]
    
[image]

The first experiment was a simple compact maze
with unwieldy sums:
[H-one-one-oneycomb](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43800/).
Next came a maze with almost-trivial sums
and additional guiding features:
[How to fill a honeymoon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43936/).

[image]
          
[image]

So it was time to explore structures
whose traversals could feel more like journeying
than like space-filling.
The conceptual point of departure was to simply have a
hexagon made of hexagons made of hexagons,
which led to a variety of possible forms.

[image]

The purest version of the hexagonal concept,
marked **12** here,
turned out to be too repetitive to be interesting.
Version **7** felt like a discovery more than a construction,
with it’s beautifully paradoxical harmonization of
6-fold and 7-fold symmetries,
as it naturally includes many different local configurations.
Version **10** wound up with rounded corners,
to avoid unnecessarily many small-scale decisions,
and that suggested the final clock format.

Would have been descriptively clean to
begin the maze at **1** o’clock and end at **12**,
but that allowed two very different overall routes,
one that was an all-too-regular zig-zag
and another much more interesting route that included
a sneaky counterclockwise inner loop
along with some zig-zags.
Both routes had the lucky feature of
forcing the hours to be visited in order.
Hah, beginning at **12** would
allow only the more interesting route.

> [image]

Now to check if this is plain too easy to
solve — or,
more likely, too tedious,
especially as arithmetic mistakes could require redoing a lot of work.
A few sloppy failed test solutions were enough to realize
that it wasn't too easy and that, surprise,
most arithmetic mistakes had only local effects.
Some analysis revealed three particularly forgiving lucky features,
labeled **A**, **B** and **C**.

> [image]

**A** demonstrates that **2**, **3** and **4** o'clock
add a combined 0 to the running total.
**B** demonstrates that any sum (or mistake)
arriving at **2** or **8** o'clock
will be multiplied by 5, which turns
all even sums$\scriptsize\raise.2ex/$mistakes into 0
and prepares odd sums$\scriptsize\raise.2ex/$mistakes
to become 0 at their inevitable next doubling.
**C** demonstrates that the clock’s inner loop has no net effect
on the peripheral loop at **9** o'clock—whew!

More fun than anticipated to analyze and test solve,
for hours and hours,
this was ready to be posed.

Comment: Fantastic puzzle, and I loved reading about the construction!