# H-one-one-oneycomb

Tags: no-computers, mazes, calculation-puzzle

[image]

**What path could a honeybee follow
to fill all cells with honey,
beginning and ending at the center
and visiting every cell exactly once?**

- At first the only honey is 1 drop in the center cell.
- Each step consists of moving to an adjacent cell and
  filling it with as many honeydrops as
  its 6 neighbors, combined, contain **at that moment**.
- The cell marked `(1)` is empty at first
  but should receive 1 honeydrop when it is reached.
  (Thus, the previous cell in the path would have 1 drop
  and no other adjacent cells would have been visited yet.)
- The cell marked `(6)` should receive 6 drops when the path gets there.
- The path ends back at the center cell,
  whose 6 adjacent cells have a total of 241 drops by then.

**No need to spoilerize a text solution.**
  Site implementation makes that unduly onerous.

The following sequence of six steps demonstrates
how the rightmost cells might be filled first.

[image]

Unknown <del>at</del> **an hour after** post time:
<del>Is there a path that ends with a smaller number than 241?</del>

What is the smallest possible ending number without the constraint of `(6)`?
Already
[ffao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPsa5.png)
and
[Jonathan Allan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/43803/18129)
have found paths under 140.

This puzzle forthrightly, though incompletely, imitates
[*Two honeycomb hints*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42884)
by
[Yuriy S](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30250/yuriy-s).

This is meant to be convenient on paper and in a text editor.
 
Here is a template for `<pre>...</pre>`:

```
                 ___                                         ___
             ___/   \___                                 ___/ ? \___
         ___/   \___/   \___                         ___/ ? \___/ ? \___
     ___/(6)\___/   \___/(1)\___                 ___/ 6 \___/ ? \___/ 1 \___
    /   \___/   \___/   \___/   \               / ? \___/ ? \___/ ? \___/ ? \
    \___/   \___/ 1 \___/   \___/     --->      \___/ ? \___/241\___/ ? \___/
    /   \___/   \___/   \___/   \               / ? \___/ ? \___/ ? \___/ ? \
    \___/   \___/   \___/   \___/               \___/ ? \___/ ? \___/ ? \___/
        \___/   \___/   \___/                       \___/ ? \___/ ? \___/
            \___/   \___/                               \___/ ? \___/
                \___/                                       \___/
```

And this is how the six-step example could begin to resemble a maze:

```
                 ___
             ___/   \___
         ___/   \___/   \___
     ___/   \___/   \___/(1)\___
    /   \___/   \___/ 1  ___  1 \
    \___/   \___/ 1  ___/ 4 \   /
    /   \___/   \___/   \     1 \
    \___/   \___/   \___/ 5 \___/
        \___/   \___/   \___/
            \___/   \___/
                \___/
```

Comment: The one on the side of the grid, does that mean that cell needs to be filled with a 1?

Comment: @humn Like, the original publication had the first letter in a larger font size. (comments deleted)

Comment: Puzzle statement now has a clearer description of the `(1)` cell, @gtwebb, sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: "Is there a path that ends with a smaller number than 241?" I believe so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hZFyG.png

Comment: Nice, @ffao, looks like 207!

Comment: @humn this one is even better at 136 (or worse, because I'm getting farther from the actual 241 goal!): http://i.stack.imgur.com/uPsa5.png

Comment: This kind of maze has a lot of potential, doesn't it, @ffao? This particular configuration was intended to be relatively compact.

Comment: @ffao - that's the same as my updated one :)

Comment: @ffao, I've included another given number. My test-solve run wasn't as directed after all as it seemed.

Comment: Good edit, @Jonathan Allan. The minimizing pre-`(6)` solutions are valuable and were what I was going for (without luck) when the 241 maze cropped up.

Comment: Both challenges were fun - 2 for the price of 1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to 241:

> ```
>                  ___
>              ___/ c \___
>          ___/ b \___/ d \___
>      ___/ p \___/ v \___/ e \___
>     / o \___/ a \___/ u \___/ g \
>     \___/ q \___/ w \___/ f \___/
>     / n \___/ r \___/ t \___/ h \
>     \___/ m \___/ s \___/ i \___/
>         \___/ l \___/ j \___/
>             \___/ k \___/
>                 \___/
> ```
>
> ```
>                  ___
>              ___/ 1 \___
>          ___/ 1 \___/ 1 \___
>      ___/ 6 \___/61 \___/ 1 \___
>     / 4 \___/ 1 \___/56 \___/ 2 \
>     \___/19 \___/241\___/ 1 \___/
>     / 4 \___/29 \___/52 \___/ 3 \
>     \___/ 4 \___/42 \___/ 4 \___/
>         \___/ 4 \___/ 4 \___/
>             \___/ 4 \___/
>                 \___/
> ```

And here is the smallest I can make:

> 136
>
> ```
>                  ___
>              ___/ c \___
>          ___/ b \___/ d \___
>      ___/ o \___/ v \___/ e \___
>     / n \___/ a \___/ u \___/ f \
>     \___/ p \___/ w \___/ t \___/
>     / m \___/ q \___/ s \___/ g \
>     \___/ l \___/ r \___/ h \___/
>         \___/ k \___/ i \___/
>             \___/ j \___/
>                 \___/
> ```
>
> ```
>                  ___
>              ___/ 1 \___
>          ___/ 1 \___/ 1 \___
>      ___/ 3 \___/48 \___/ 1 \___
>     / 1 \___/ 1 \___/43 \___/ 1 \
>     \___/ 7 \___/136\___/22 \___/
>     / 1 \___/11 \___/18 \___/ 1 \
>     \___/ 1 \___/15 \___/ 1 \___/
>         \___/ 1 \___/ 1 \___/
>             \___/ 1 \___/
>                 \___/
> ```

Comment: How do I get that in a spoiler? It all gets messed up!

Comment: Makes no difference it removes loads of the underscores and backslashes.

Comment: @JonathanAllan you have to escape all of the backslashes with \\

Comment: Got 241... now to edit it in.

Comment: I tried this run before humn gave the extra digit, but I miscalculated it as 251... :/

Comment: All my efforts prior to the extra digit were too low, I realised he must have gone that way and got to the other side of `(6)` with `4` somehow.

Comment: Good for both of you @ffao and $@$Jonathan Allan!  Easy to mis-add. Thank you for helping try out this kind of maze.  Future ones will be more sophisticated and better test-solved (and made by others?).

Comment: Might have another moment of fun in store on this one, if `r`=`27` is really `29`. The compensating fix will be minor, but where? Great way to recruit the alphabet too, by the way.

Comment: @JonathanAllan shouldn't the 11 in the second set be a 10? If so, you actually have 115 not 136.

Comment: @dcfyj Nope - there are four ones and a seven around it - the starting point has a drop right from the get-go.

Comment: Ah, that's why. I wasn't counting the starting drop

Comment: @humn - the rth step to be `29` and `(6)` still there and final is `241`?

Comment: Right, @Jonathan Allan, you can make a minor route alteration elsewhere to compensate. (Just as a check, I get 29 from 1+1+19+4+4.)

Comment: Many thanks for making the spoiler work, @ffao, and
for continuing the good fight against that
feature of the website, $@$Jonathan Allan!
(From a feeling of guilt, though,
 the puzzle statement has been revised to badmouth the site
 and to reassure that spoilerizing text is not required.)

Comment: So I was right when I got 251! Faith in my arithmetic restored.

Comment: @humn oops -more haste, less speed - thanks!